# Is this space Hilbert space?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, hilbert-spaces, lp-spaces

Let's say we have linear space
$$
\ell^2 := \{x=(x_1, x_2, ..): \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} x_i^2 < \infty \}
$$
with
$$
<x,y> := \sum_{i=i}^{\infty} \lambda_i x_i y_i
$$
where $\lambda_i \in \mathbb{R}$, $ 0 < \lambda_i <1$.

Is this space Hilbert space and is this $<x,y>$ Euclidean?

Comment: What do you mean by Euclidean?

Comment: Are the $x_i$ real? The only definition of a euclidean space I know is that the scalar product is defined on a real vector space. Are you maybe asked to verify that this is a "real" scalar product?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function $\langle x, y \rangle = \sum_i \lambda_i x_iy_i$ does define and inner-product; I assume that this is what you mean by "Euclidean".

That being said, the space $\ell^2$ might not be a Hilbert space under this inner product since it might fail to be complete.  For instance, if we take $\lambda_i = 2^{-i}$ and define the sequence $(x^{(k)})_{k \in \Bbb N}$ by
$$
x^{(k)}(j) = \begin{cases}
1 & j \leq k\\
0 & j > k,
\end{cases}
$$
then we find that $x^{(k)}$ is Cauchy relative to the norm induced by this new inner product, but fails to have a limit in $\ell^2$.

Comment: Agreed.  The space that is complete for this inner product is $$\left\{x=(x_1, x_2, ..): \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \lambda_i x_i^2 < \infty \right\}$$